# How can I store/retrieve a JSON object that contains a function to fetch fresh data?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, caching, serialization

```
const Data = {
    teachers: {
        size: 15,
        num: 4,
        color: 'blue'
    }
}

const person = {
    name: 'John',
    group: Data.teachers, // This is Default. If I do this, the entire teachers tree gets cached. Later, teachers tree changes, this is unusable.
    group: () => Data.teachers // I want to do this, so that it fetches fresh data. But, see below for the LJSON problem...
}
```

I understand that JSON.stringify does not support functions.

I've looked into LJSON (https://github.com/MaiaVictor/LJSON).  LJSON does not fix the problem.  They also cache Data.teachers, as is.  When using LJSON, if `Data.teachers` changes, then calling `group()` will *not* get the latest.  It will return the old tree.

(Current stack is React-Native, with AsyncStorage, using JSON.stringify/parse.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `toString()` method of a `Function` & `eval`?

```js
const fn = (arg) => {
  console.log('function:', arg)
}
fn('yes, it works')

const jsonFn = JSON.stringify(fn.toString()) // now its a JSON.stringified string
const newJsonFn = JSON.parse(jsonFn) // parsing it back from JSON to string
const newFn = eval(newJsonFn) // eval!!!
newFn('yes, it works again')
```

### IMPORTANT

Yes, this snippet solves your problem. But don't forget that `eval` is a dangerous tool: [about eval security issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript).